# Get a checkbox variable from another activity in Android

Tags: java, android, variables, checkbox

I need some help getting a checkbox's state. Basically I want to get if a checkbox from an activity is checked then if it is, show some text on the main activity. I've read lots and lots of SO Q&As but nothing worked. I got this:

```
CheckBox show = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

public CheckBox getShow() {
    return show;
}
```

So I'd use

```
CheckBox setty = Settings.getCheck();
```

on the other class. But I get an error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getCheck()'

How can I do this? I need to get if it's on or off and display it on the main activity. Remember that I can't use Intents because I won't have a button to transition, the text and value must be always there on the main class.

Comment: All activities are started by intents. So you can pass data from one activity to the other by putting data in the intent's extra field. If you are returning from one activity, to pass the result, you can start activity for result from the initial activity. So U dont need a getter for the checkbox as shown in ur code

Comment: Read the post please, the main activity may contain the value true or false as soon as it starts. I can't make the user open another activity, just if they wanna modify it @AdityaK

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared preference to store a checkbox check/uncheck value..and based on that value you can show text in your other activity.

here is the code:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
```

initialize shared preference in onCreate() method of first activity

```
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);

  //now initialize listener for checkbox

   check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("checked", "1");
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("checked", "0");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now in another activity you just have to load the shared preference data and show message based on condition

```
public void Load_checkbox() {
        //define MyPREFERENCES in other activity too- same as first activity
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        if (shared.getString("checked", "").equals("1")) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CheckBox Checked " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CheckBox unchecked " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

call this Load_checkbox() method in your second activity where u want to check the checkbox state of first activity